# How to use a JavaScript method/object that has been defined in another file?

Tags: javascript

I have a some JavaScript with a complex structure. Because I'm new comer to JavaScript (only understanding some basic concepts) I don't know how to use it properly.

I have two files : Circle.js and Line.js. In Circle.js, I want to use a class object defined in Line.js:

In file Circle.js :

```
Helper.using('py.Figures', function (ns) {

    ns.Circle = function (params) {
        // some additional methods and code here
    }
}
```

And in Line.js is :

```
Helper.using('py.Figures', function (ns) {

        ns.Line2Point = function (params) {
            // some addition methods and code here
        };
}
```

In Figures.Circle,  in ns.Circle I want to use Line2Point but I don't know how.
I think it should be :

```
line = new ns.Line2Point(params);
```

But It seem doesn't work.

According to `Helper Class`, `ns` will point to `helper.using`, in this case `py.Figures`. Does it mean, `ns` is the same object/reference in both the files?

Comment: None of this is standard javascript or a commonly used library

Comment: what does your mean ? please tell me clearer. thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is doable in Javascript directly across files. If they are part of the same namespace you could share some 'global' objects to achieve this have the line2points and circles attach themselves to that global object:

Ex:

```
var myShapesNameSpace = {};
```

Circle.js:

```
(function(){
  var circle = {};
  circle.method1 = function(){...}
  circle.method2 = function(){...}

  myShapesNameSpace.Circles = circle;

})(window.myShapesNameSpace = window.myShapesNameSpace || {}); //check if namespace object exists. Else create a new blank one.
```

Line.js:

```
(function(){
  var line= {};
  line.method1 = function(){...}
  line.method2 = function(){...}

  myShapesNameSpace.Lines= line;

})(window.myShapesNameSpace = window.myShapesNameSpace || {});
```

Now you can check for the existence of `myShapesNameSpace.Circles` or `.Lines` and call the corresponding methods accordingly.

You can include files in javascript and reference objects across files unless they are exported in some global form either via window or your define global

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Javascript, the shit parts. Require.js was designed precisely for this because the creators of JS, well, I guess thought that everyone would write every program in one file.

[RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/)

It was designed for web use but can be used elsewhere too (locally, with Node, etc.)